# How to add response header in VHost or Passeneger (Ruby)

Tags: passenger, redmine, virtualhost, cors

I have problem with Same Origin Policy. I want to make cross domain request - I found nice solution: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

But I don't want set header in Apache because I have there many domains and only one need it. Is it possible to add **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header via Virtual Host or Passenger?

I do it, because I need use Redmine REST API (XHR) in Chrome/Mozilla plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement. If you want Redmine to serve these headers then you need to modify the Redmine source. I've written [a blog post about doing this](http://richard-towers.com/2013/01/13/cors-with-redmine.html).

Credit to [this blog post](http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428) for most of the details.

I'll reproduce what I had to do here for convenience:

---

First let's adress the preflight check. I've added a whole new controller, just for this, at `/app/controllers/cors_controller.rb`. It looks like:

```ruby
class CorsController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_filter :session_expiration, :user_setup, :check_if_login_required, :set_localization

    def preflight
            headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
            headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
            headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Content-Type'
            headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
            render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end

end
```

Pretty simple stuff. I've then routed all `OPTIONS` requests to this controller in `/config/routes.rb`:

```ruby
match '*path', :to => 'cors#preflight', :constraints => {:method => 'OPTIONS'}
```

Preflight checks taken care of, it's just a case of adding the headers to the main response using an `after_filter` in `/app/controllers/application_controller.rb` as suggested by Tom:

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Redmine::I18n
  # ...
  before_filter :session_expiration, :user_setup, :check_if_login_required, :set_localization

  #************ Begin Added Code ****************
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

  # For all responses in this application, return the CORS access control headers.

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end
  #************* End Added Code *****************
  #...
end
```